# Create Vector of Length n in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to create a vector/array of length `n` to be filled afterwards.

How can I do that?
And does it have to be filled already with something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For example if you want a Vector of Ints of length 10 you can write

```
v = Vector{Int}(undef, 10)
```

And more general for an Array of Ints of dimensions (2, 3, 4)

```
a = Array{Int}(undef, (2, 3, 4))
```

Note that this fills the Vector/Array with garbage values, so this can be a bit dangerous. As an alternative you can use

```
v = Vector{Int}()
sizehint!(v, 10)
push!(v, 1) # add a one to the end of the Vector
append!(v, (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) # add values 2 to 9 to the end of the vector
```

`sizehint!` is not necessary, but it can improve performance, because it tells Julia to expect 10 values.

There are other functions such as `zeros`, `ones` or `fill` that can provide a Vector/Array with already filled in data.